# Finding a system of linear equations from solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Is there a simple way to find the system of linear equations given the solutions?
For example, find a system with 2 equations and 3 variables that has solutions (1, 4, -1) and (2, 5, 2).

I get:

```
x1 - x2 = -3
3x1 - x3 = 4
```

The method I used to get this answer was guessing and checking, but surely there is a simpler and more efficient way to go about it?

Also, are there other equations that would fit this solution set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution set of your system of equations is not simply $\{(1,4,-1), (2,5,2)    \}$.

For example, $(0,3,-4)$ is a solution. There are infinitely many others.

And we cannot obtain a system of two linear equations in three unknowns whose solution set is
$\{(1,4,-1), (2,5,2)    \}$.  For if the system has a solution, it has infinitely many.

As to your question about producing such a system in a systematic way, let the two equations be $a_1x+b_1y+c_1z=d_1$, $a_2x+b_2y+c_2z=d_2$. The conditions are
$a_1+4b_1-c_1=d_1$, $2a_1+5b_1+2c_1=d_1$, $a_2+4b_2-c_2=d_2$, $2a_2+5b_2+2c_2=d_2$.

We have $4$ equations in $8$ unknowns, so obviously a lot of slack.  One way to cut down on it is to decide that the $d_i$ will be $0$.

Choose say $a_1=0$, and solve for $b_1$ and $c_1$; Choose $b_2=0$, and solve for $a_2$ and $c_2$.