# Is it possible to find general solution to 3 linear equations with 4 variables having only 2 particular solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is simple - I would like to know if it's possible to describe general solution in the system of 3 linear equations with 4 variables ONLY with an information that (1, 2, 3, 4) and (2, 0, 0, 1) are particular solutions. I've tried to do it for so long that at this point I am not sure if it's even possible.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think constraining yourself to only these two possible solutions is practical because the possible solutions depend on the rank of the equations and variables when you put them into a matrix. From you description, if you put them into an m by n matrix, the m will be 3 and n will be 4. If your matrix has rank lesser than m, it will have no solution or only one solution but if the rank is greater than m but less than n it would have practically an infinite number of solutions because of the null space. But since the n > m, then you are guaranteed to have in either case an infinite number of solutions. So, what you are looking at in the worst case is a matrix that has 0, or infinite solutions. (1,2,3,4) and (2,0,0, 1) might be among the infinite solutions.

Comment: Thank you Sir! As I found out I could actually turn those 3 linear equations into 6 equations with 15 variables (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507153/finding-a-system-of-linear-equations-from-solutions). However I was just wondering if there is a way to use matrix in some more creative way. I know I can create 2 matrixes for those 2 solutions